# Send an EOF in Eclipse's debugger console

Tags: c, eclipse

I have a program that takes console input that I'm trying to debug. Sending an EOF (Ctrl+D in shell) is important to its function; but Ctrl+D doesn't send one in Eclipse's debugger console.

This should be super simple, but Google (and my limited experience) yields nothing. Thanks so much for any help!

Comment: What OS? What version of Eclipse?

Comment: My bad, Ubuntu 10.10, Eclipse 3.5.2

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing End of Transmission (Ctrl + D) character in Eclipse CDT console](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4711098/passing-end-of-transmission-ctrl-d-character-in-eclipse-cdt-console)

Comment: Yep, it is. I will try to figure out how to close this as a duplicate.

Comment: Still happening in OpenSUSE 12 & Eclipse CDT Luna 4.4.1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a bug, see here:

[Passing End of Transmission (Ctrl + D) character in Eclipse CDT console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4711098/passing-end-of-transmission-ctrl-d-character-in-eclipse-cdt-console)

Answer (score 16):

I just found a solution to this problem:

When you finish entering your inputs on console, click on another window (editor, Project Explorer, etc.), then click back on console. Hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> will work now.

Comment: Exactly. This workaround is mentioned in J.Weimer comment on the bug report https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=159803

Answer (score 2):

I think it(not responding to Ctrl+D on Unix/Linux systems and not responding to Ctrl+Z on DOS?Windows systems) was a bug some 2 3 years back.  Eclipse mailing lists or bugs database should have better information about it.  Refer [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=159803) for more info on the bug report.

Comment: Exactly. It is a cross platform bug concerning End Of File Character, which maps to Ctrl+D on Unix/Linux systems and Ctrl+Z on DOS.

Answer (score 0):

On mac for C++ projects try to disable this feature:
Go to Run -> Run configurations... 
Uncheck Connect process input & output to a terminal. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the trick by focusing something else and then refocussing the console only works in the 'normal' perspective, and not in the debugging perspective for me.

Another workaround is to use an external console. This can be configured here:

- Press `Run` in the upper menu
- Choose `Debug` Configurations
- Go to the `Debugger` tab
- Check `Use external console for inferior (open a new console window for input/output)`

[image]

Works for both the normal perspective and the debugging perspective for me.