# Eclipse debugging with input from console

Tags: c++, eclipse, debugging

I'm trying to debug a program I wrote in C++ using Eclipse.
The program includes getting input from the user but when I enter the input to the console it won't ever continue running the code (it'll keep asking for input). 
I can't debug without fixing this and would appreciate some help.
Thank you.

The code gets stuck on the while loop fgets:

```
int main(int argc, const char**argv) {
    FILE* inputFile = NULL;

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    if(argc == 2){
        inputFile = fopen(argv[1], "r");
        if (inputFile == NULL){
            printf("Problem opening file %s, make sure correct path name is given.\n", argv[1]);
            return 0;
        }
    }
    else {
        inputFile = stdin;
    }

    char buffer[MAX_STRING_INPUT_SIZE];
    // Reading commands
    while ( fgets(buffer, MAX_STRING_INPUT_SIZE, inputFile) != NULL ) {
        fflush(stdout);
        if ( parser(buffer) == error ){
            printf("ERROR\n");
            break;
        }
    };
    fclose(inputFile);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you attach relevant code here?

Comment: Do you get the same problem running the program outside of Eclipse as a stand alone executable?

Comment: See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4711098/passing-end-of-transmission-ctrl-d-character-in-eclipse-cdt-console

Comment: Sounds like an infinite loop.

Comment: It's not. When I run it in the terminal it works.

Comment: Did you check the debug configuration? AFAIR there's some option to assign a console to the executable being debugged.

Answer (score 14):

The issue comes from Eclipse buffering the console inputs.
One way to fix it is to force Eclipse to debug using a Windows/DOS native console.

The procedure is described in details [here](http://nicolas.riousset.com/eclipse-how-to-debug-a-c-console-application-using-a-native-dos-console-instead-of-the-ide-integrated-one/), but in brief :

1. Create your Hello World C++ command line project, from the Eclipse menu File > New > C++ Project
2. In your project folder, create a ".gdbinit" text file. It will contain your gdb debugger configuration
3. Edit ".gdbinit", and add the following line (without quotes) : "set new-console on"
4. In Eclipse, go to menu Run > "Debug Configurations", and select your application name in the left pane
5. In the "debugger" tab, ensure the "GDB command file" now points to your « .gdbinit » file. Else, input the path to your ".gdbinit" configuration file
6. Click « Apply » and « Debug ». You’re done ! A native DOS command line should be launched.

Comment: how to stop Eclipse buffering the console inputs while 'Running the Application As'(not dedugging) too?

Answer (score 0):

Well I know that Eclipse console buffer doesn't always work as it should - in my experiences, it's the worst when using C or C++.

If you want to run your compiled code in Eclipse, this will *greatly help* but **not eliminate** the display issues you might encounter in Eclipse:

`setvbuf(stdout, NULL, 0, _IONBF);`

**However**, I don't know how this affects debugging in Eclipse while using `stdin`. Your *best* option is to use [Nicolas's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19824801/1986871) to run through the DOS console. A bit more work, but it will suffice I believe.

And please note that the above line should **only** be used while running your code through Eclipse, in order to have some kind of sane output buffer without several messy in-code workarounds. This line needs to be **commented out** when compiling for actual use.