# How do I debug a c++ program in eclipse when I have some input to be passed at the runtime?

Tags: c++, eclipse, debugging

I am trying to debug a simple c++ program, which takes some inputs at the runtime.
When i start debugging, it just stops where I should input the values. But after that it does not run. When i click on resume, still it does not. Can someone help me how can i get this debugged. Thank you so much.

```
#include "iostream"

using namespace std;

void selection_sort(int *a, int n){
    int i,j,temp,pos,smallest;
    for (i=0; i<n; i++){              ### i have a debug point here
        smallest = a[i];
        for(j=i; j<n; j++){
            if(smallest > a[j]){
                smallest = a[j];
                pos = j;
            }
        }
        temp = a[i];
        a[i]=smallest;
        a[pos] = temp;
    }
}

int main(){
    int arr[10],i;
    for (i=0;i<10;i++)     ## the eclipse debugger i.e. gdb stops here, as I have to input some values
        cin >> arr[i];
    selection_sort(arr,10);
    cout << "\nafter sorting:\n";
    for (i=0;i<10;i++)
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
    return 0;
}
`
```

Comment: And as it waits for you to input, did you input and press enter?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Eclipse debugging with input from console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14324487/eclipse-debugging-with-input-from-console). Note: That question is a little outdated. Now, you just need to go into your debugging configuration, open the debugger tab, and enable the use external console option. You're going to have to do this for each project.

Comment: Also, C++ comments use `//`, not `##`.

Comment: And how do I enable the use of external console option? Thanks

Comment: I'm still stuck with this. Would appreciate any help on this. Thank you.