# Run C++ code on command prompt window in Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, cmd, windows-10

I would like to have my code run on a command prompt window instead of the eclipse console. I use eclipse on a windows 10.

Comment: Does this answer your question: [Eclipse debugging with input from console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14324487/eclipse-debugging-with-input-from-console)?

Comment: Okay that methods describes doing it in debug mode but I want achieve this in run. But I tried the method anyways the cmd window pop up and exits immediately

Comment: Can't help with run. Best suggestion there is to have a command prompt open in the release folder and run the program in it as required. If the command prompt insta-closes when debugging, place a breakpoint at the beginning of the program and find out why.