# How do we terminate this C code?

Tags: c, eof

This c code is from K&R. It is running continuously, even when I type -1. I am using eclipse in fedora 17. whats wrong with this code? how would it terminate? Even CTRL+D not working to end it!

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int c;

    c = getchar();
    while(c != EOF)
    {
        putchar(c);
        c = getchar();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `-1` is two characters: a minus sign and a digit 1.

Comment: Ah, your code is fine.  Miracle of miracles, this is actually a bug in _Eclipse_: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4711098/passing-end-of-transmission-ctrl-d-character-in-eclipse-cdt-console

Answer (score 4):

> It is running continuously, even when I type -1

On Unix you need to type Ctrl-D instead to signal end of file.

---

As Mooing Duck points out, [this seems to be a bug in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4711098/passing-end-of-transmission-ctrl-d-character-in-eclipse-cdt-console).

Comment: I tried that. but it didn't work in eclipse IDE. but outside eclipse, in terminal window, CTRL + D is working fine! Its sorted out now.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4711098/passing-end-of-transmission-ctrl-d-character-in-eclipse-cdt-console

Answer (score 3):

Send the EOF character.

In Linux in a terminal use CTRL-D.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4711098/passing-end-of-transmission-ctrl-d-character-in-eclipse-cdt-console

Answer (score 3):

It turned out to be a problem with eclipse IDE. outside eclipse, code is running fine. CTRL+D for unix is the EOF (internally -1).
There is a workaround in eclipse. for each application that needs EOF, goto RUN --> RUN CONFIGURATION... --> in the main tab scroll down and uncheck ' connect process input and output to a terminal'.
now run the code. CTRL+D should work. for each application you have to apply this trick separately.

Answer (score -1):

in Mac is Cmd + D also. Im pretty sure in windows is Windows + D

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4711098/passing-end-of-transmission-ctrl-d-character-in-eclipse-cdt-console