# Eclipse - how can I stop my program?

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char c;
    ofstream outFile("/home/gnome/Music/file.txt", ios::out);
    while (cin >> c) {
        outFile.put(c);
    }
    outFile.close();

    return 0;
}
```

When I want to stop, I can't interrupt it with a control-D like I do on the the Linux terminal. How do I do this in eclipse. The issue is that, It doesn't write any char to my file. When I cat the file, it's empty, and the past data is gone. Empty. I used this code with g++ on the terminal, and it works.
How do I use this in eclipse?

[Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8NbiF.png)

Comment: Or maybe Ctrl+C.

Comment: I used that ctrl-z, and it's still not working.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Ctrl-Z worked for me using Eclipse Oxygen 3 on Windows 10.

Comment: Anything in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4711098/passing-end-of-transmission-ctrl-d-character-in-eclipse-cdt-console help?

Comment: I use Ubuntu-Mate  18.04 LTS Bionic.

Comment: Never tried this on Linux, but do you get a system console if you place a .gdbinit file containing "set new-console on" into the projects root folder? If so, does it respect the usual ctrl+ keys?

Comment: user4581301 Workaround checkbox no longer available in UI.

Comment: I placed the .gdbinit file under /home/gnome and it's still not working.

Comment: It works fine for me in `eclipse` on `Linux`. Perhaps make sure the console window has input focus by clicking on it?

Comment: Ctrl-D works, but if I use it before Ctrl-Z, it does not.

Comment: @Galik Yes, it has focus. I put "text", then I see my file with cat, nano, and the file is empty

Comment: I downloaded from the official web page, I didn't installed from repos, if the helps. It's a lot buggy, because it doesn't recognize "endl" sometimes, for example. Many bugs.

Comment: I created a file called "file.txt" inside the project, and It works great. I don't know why writing to the file outside the project doesn't work.

Comment: @Frank So is it the `Ctrl-D` that is not working or the *writing to a file* that is not working?

Comment: @Galik It's the writing to a file. It works only locally, inside the project folder, not outside.